# Vectorised solution for iterating through a list of indices and updating a corresponding matrix

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I have a list of lists of the following form

```
xx = list("a_1" = list("A", "C"), 
          "a_2" = list("B", "C"), 
          "a_3" = list("B", "B"), 
          "a_4" = list("C", "B"), 
          "a_5" = list("B", "A"),
          "a_6" = list("B", "A"))
```

Note that this list contains sublists that are duplicates, like "a_5" and "a_6" in the above example. Using this list of lists, I want to update a matrix of the form

```
m = matrix(data = 0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)         # initialise matrix of zeros
rownames(m) = c("A", "B", "C")                   # name rows
colnames(m) = c("A", "B", "C")                   # name columns
```

such that we add one to the index of the matrix corresponding to a given pair. This is easy to do using a for loop

```
for (item in xx) {
  
  # add one to the matrix index if item in xx
  m[item[[1]], item[[2]]] = m[item[[1]], item[[2]]] + 1
  
}
```

which yields the expected output

```
  A B C
A 0 0 1
B 2 1 1
C 0 1 0
```

though this can be slightly cumbersome for large lists. I was hoping to do this in a vectorised way using the `apply()` methods but I wasn't able to get anything working using a nested combination of `lapply()` to iterate through the list and `sapply()` to update the values to the matrix.

So I was wondering how to do this using variant(s) of `apply()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fully vectorized:

```
x <- matrix(unlist(xx), length(xx), 2, 1)
m + tabulate(
  match(x[,1], row.names(m)) + nrow(m)*(match(x[,2], colnames(m)) - 1L),
  length(m)
)
#>   A B C
#> A 0 0 1
#> B 2 1 1
#> C 0 1 0
```

### Benchmarking

Define the various approaches as functions.

```
floop <- function(m, xx) {
  for (item in xx) m[item[[1]], item[[2]]] = m[item[[1]], item[[2]]] + 1L
  m
}

fsapply <- function(mm, xx) {
  sapply(xx, \(x) mm[x[[1]], x[[2]]] <<- mm[x[[1]], x[[2]]] + 1L)
  mm
}

faggregate <- function(m, xx) {
  sel <- data.frame(t(sapply(xx, unlist)))
  sel <- aggregate(cbind(sel[0], value=1), sel, FUN=sum)
  m[as.matrix(sel[1:2])] <- m[as.matrix(sel[1:2])] + sel$value
  m
}

fvectorized <- function(m, xx) {
  x <- matrix(unlist(xx), length(xx), 2, 1)
  m + tabulate(
    match(x[,1], row.names(m)) + nrow(m)*(match(x[,2], colnames(m)) - 1L),
    length(m)
  )
}

ftable <- function(m, xx) {
  m + c(table(as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(xx), length(xx), 2, 1))))
}
```

Create a larger test example:

```
xx <- lapply(1:1e4, \(i) as.list(sample(LETTERS, 2, 1)))
m <- matrix(0L, 26, 26, 0, rep(list(LETTERS), 2))
```

Benchmark:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  floop = floop(m, xx),
  fsapply = fsapply(m, xx),
  faggregate = faggregate(m, xx),
  fvectorized = fvectorized(m, xx),
  ftable = ftable(m, xx),
  check = "equal"
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>         expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>        floop  8611.9  9051.65 11519.122  9877.15 12723.70 54497.1   100
#>      fsapply 15160.5 15813.15 17868.492 17069.90 19383.50 28591.2   100
#>   faggregate 14888.5 15540.90 16733.166 16100.20 17810.55 20828.0   100
#>  fvectorized   910.6  1019.10  1201.803  1078.90  1226.75  5886.9   100
#>       ftable  1297.0  1573.40  1765.658  1691.40  1823.95  4364.7   100
```

Comment: wow apply is just a glorified loop! I imagine map isn't much different 

Comment: I suppose the sapply()` option was what I was looking for, but the benchmarking made it clear that the `apply()` methods are not always the best option for speed. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3):

what about this `table` approach?

```
> table(as.data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(xx), 2))))
   V2
V1  A B C
  A 0 0 1
  B 2 1 1
  C 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a `row/column` pair index matrix and then overwrite:

```
sel <- t(sapply(xx, unlist))
m[sel] <- m[sel] + 1
m
#  A B C
#A 0 0 1
#B 1 1 1
#C 0 1 0
```

To deal with duplicates, maybe something like:

```
sel <- data.frame(t(sapply(xx, unlist)))
sel <- aggregate(cbind(sel[0], value=1), sel, FUN=sum)
m[as.matrix(sel[1:2])] <- m[as.matrix(sel[1:2])] + sel$value
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems that this doesn't add one when it hits a duplicate index pair. For example, `xx = list("a_1" = list("A", "C"), "a_2" = list("B", "C"), "a_3" = list("B", "B"), "a_4" = list("C", "B"), "a_5" = list("B", "A"), "a_6" = list("B", "A"))` returns the same array as using `xx` without the `"a_6"` entry.

Comment: @MatthewCassell - that's a good point. I don't think this will deal with such a circumstance. I'll have a think about how to address that.

Comment: @MatthewCassell - see my edit for how to deal with dups.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner:

```
purrr::map(xx, \(x) m[x[[1]], x[[2]]] <<- m[x[[1]], x[[2]]] + 1)
```

It's exactly the same with sapply:

```
sapply(xx, \(x) m[x[[1]], x[[2]]] <<- m[x[[1]], x[[2]]] + 1)
```

Comment: I suppose the sapply()` option was what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.